# How to display the details of the particular data Mouse over it using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery-ui, codeigniter, jquery

I need to display the all the contents of a username when the user **Mouse over** the usernames and the output should to be similar to a pop or a iframe.How to achieve this?

```
         $('#previousIssuedDetail').live('mouseover', function() {
         $(this).addClass('row_over');
         });
```

but not able to display it

Comment: you need to try something, make some html/css using position properties for the element and do some jquery mouseover stuff's then post here your result/questions.

Comment: have tried it... but its not working

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this ?

```
<div id="acc">Acc
   <ul id="ulAcc">
       <li>User</li>    
       <li>User 2</li>   
       <li>User 3</li>   
   </ul>
</div>​
```

js

```
$("#acc").hover(function(){
   $(this).children().stop(true,true).slideDown(); 
   }, function(){
   $(this).children().stop(true,true).slideUp();     
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wUsXw/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please tell what exactly is the problem?

The easiest way to get it would be like this.
Define you html like this -

```
<dl class="user">
<dt class="username">Username</dt>
<dd class="userdetails>User Details</dd>
</dl>
```

Now, in the CSS file, you can write this -

```
.userdetails { display: none; }
.user:hover > .userdetails { display: block; }
```

You can also write a jquery script to get it done too.
Or, just customize the css this way, and you can do it without using jquery.

Comment: +1 for reminding me the existance of `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>`. There's so much tags we never use that we could take advantage of.

Comment: But `visible` is not a valid value for `display`. You probably mean `inline`.

Comment: yea... there is brilliant article on these. Read [this](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/13/how-to-use-dl-dt-and-dd-html-tags-to-list-data-vs-table-list-data/) and [this](http://www.benmeadowcroft.com/webdev/articles/definition-lists/)

Comment: yea... sorry. make it `display: box` or `display: inline`